# face recognition using kinect using points getting from the face tracking basics?

Tags: kinect

Is there any algorithm face recognition using the points getting from the "Face Tracking Basics" given by Microsoft?

Now I am using the below code. But I am not getting a correct value

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.facePoints.Count - 1; i++)
{
  Total += ((facePoints[i].Y + facePoints[i+1].Y) / (facePoints[i].Y -facePoints   [i+1].Y));
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use it as a unique login system? Since not every face is unique per user..

Comment: i just want recognize a person.  i am new in this.  i just want to try opencv. can u just help me for that?

Comment: there are built-in samples in the Developer Toolkit on Facetracking with kinect.